# few subdomains resolve while others dont

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, subdomain, godaddy

We have a *.mydomain.com setup in godaddy A-type record pointing to same IP address. The problem occurring that occasional some domains are resolving to correct IP address and one subdomain does not. after some random time, it also works perfect. and this also happens differently to machines within the same network.

machineA can't resolve a.mydoamin.com, machineB can.
machineA and machineB both  can resolve b.mydoamin.com

We have dns expiry/TTL set to 24 hours. 
Please suggest.

Im also thinking to try to resolve wildcard with a CNAME of mydomain.com. could it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the domain's DNS provided by more than one DNS server? Perhaps you have multiple DNS servers whose configuration doesn't match. So the systems getting different answers at different times, may be querying different servers...

Can you use 'dig' or similar to manually perform some lookups?

```
dig soa mydomain.com
```

should include a list of name servers ("NS" records).

Comment: It has 2 entries in NS record as suggested by godaddy. which seems fine.

Comment: ok, but do both of those DNS servers respond with the same information. If you "dig some.th.ing @ns1.yadda" and compare to "dig some.th.ing @ns2.yadda" do they match? Once you're certain the two DNS servers have equal records, then I'd start using dig (or nslookup) on the systems in question to see where they're getting their answers from.